# Get active menu selected in HTML

Tags: html, css, menu, nav

I want to have something like that when I click on a link in my Menu.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
        <li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

How can I have this active class when I choose another link ?

Comment: I want to change the active current class when I click on another link

Comment: You'll need a serverside script (ie PHP) to add an active class. Or look for a javascript solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you havent mentioned using it, one solution would be to use something like jQuery to toggle the active class on clicked items, e.g (rough code only):

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
   $('li').removeClass('active');
   $(this).toggleClass('active');
})
```

## **[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2zBws/)**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2zBws/13/ i have edited your fiddle, if you want you can use this as your sample Fiddle..!! Great work..!! +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

To fully accomplish your task you need a server side lang.

e.g.

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === "your_url" ) echo 'id="active"'; ?>
```

yes, you can use JavaScript OR Jquery this will not work if JavaScript is disabled in a brower !